# SSE implementation in Spark REST

Tags: server-sent-events, spark-framework

Looking for a simple example of a GET rest api that produces text/event-stream. How do I keep a track of listeners, how to use emitter in spark? Basically, how do I achieve SSE using spark framework (Server side code)

Comment: What SSE, Server-Sent Events? That has its own tag.

Comment: Yes, server-sent events

Comment: @SoniaGupta where you able to get an example/help?  (I am looking for similar)

Comment: any solution about this?